# Which is more performant at scale, `className` or `ref`?

Tags: reactjs, performance, ref

I have a lot of elements on the screen, so I need a lot of unique identifiers for them. I can do it using `className="uniqueItem"` or `ref={ref => this.uniqueItem = ref}` so which is more performant when there are many components re-rendering often?

Answer (score 0):

Ref would be fine as it would also give you high reusability which in the case of className would be less.

But speaking of performance, className will be more performant.

Comment: may be common knowledge, but any jsperf link or url reference to back that claim ?

Comment: The reason I question this is because DOM elements tagged by `ref` seem to be available earlier in the React lifecycle than elements tagged by `className` so this leads me to guess `ref` would be more performant.